How to pass testcontext from beforeAll to other tests?
I using Playwright with TypeScript. In one of my test suites I'm using beforeAll method.
The tests failed and after some digging it turn out that the testContext in the beforeAll method is Not the same testContext in my tests.
Please note: all my tests have to get testContext as parameter, I can not change the code to get page or browser.
test.beforeAll(async ({ testContext }) => {        
        const authApi = await testContext.getApi(AuthApi)
        const res = await authApi.login(
            configProvider.loginEmail,
            configProvider.loginPassword
        )       
        homePage = await testContext.getPage(HomePage, {
            shouldNavigate: true,
        })
    })

 test('Test1 - create', async ({ testContext }) => {
    
        // here I need to same testContext as If I used beforeEach and not beforeAll
    })

How can I solve this?

You can fix it but setting the scope of the fixture to worker. See docs.
Fixture
import { test as base, expect } from '@playwright/test';

// Define the types for the fixtures
type MyFixtures = {
  sharedTestContext: any;
};

class Incrementer {
  private value: number;

  constructor() {
    this.value = 0;
  }

  get() {
    this.value += 1;
    return this.value;
  }
}


const test = base.extend<MyFixtures>({
  sharedTestContext: [async ({}, use) => {
    const testContext = new Incrementer();
    await use(testContext);
  }, { scope: 'worker' }],
});

export { test, expect };

Test
import { test } from './fixtures';

test.beforeAll(async ({ sharedTestContext }) => {
  // Log the sharedTestContext and homePage in beforeEach to confirm they are the same
  console.log(sharedTestContext.get());
});

test.beforeEach(async ({ sharedTestContext }) => {
  // Log the sharedTestContext and homePage in beforeEach to confirm they are the same
  console.log(sharedTestContext.get());
});

test('Test1 - create', async ({ sharedTestContext }) => {
  // Use the shared testContext from the fixture
  console.log(sharedTestContext.get());
});

Output
➜  testFixtureQuestion npx playwright test

Running 1 test using 1 worker
[chromium] › example.spec.ts:8:5 › Test1 - create
1
2
3
  1 passed (354ms)

